# Decoding JSON.stringify in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm sending the following string trough a javascript function into a PHP file:

```
    function showcart()
{
    document.getElementById('cart').value = JSON.stringify(paypal.minicart.cart.items());
}
```

On PHP side the string comes as follows:

```
echo $_POST['cart'];
```

```
[{"_data":{"cmd":"_cart","add":"1","item_name":"FILA 1010302","item_image":"images/1010302-1.png","amount":99,"discount_amount":"50.00","submit":"Adicionar ao carrinho","quantity":2,"href":"http://teste/index.html#5"},"_options":[],"_discount":100,"_amount":99,"_total":98,"_eventCache":{"change":[[null,null]]}},{"_data":{"cmd":"_cart","add":"1","item_name":"FILA 1010575","item_image":"images/1010575-1.png","amount":99,"discount_amount":"50.00","submit":"Adicionar ao carrinho","quantity":1,"href":"http://teste/index.html#5"},"_options":[],"_discount":50,"_amount":99,"_total":49,"_eventCache":{"change":[[null,null]]}},{"_data":{"cmd":"_cart","add":"1","item_name":"FILA 1010707","item_image":"images/1010707-1.png","amount":99,"discount_amount":"50.00","submit":"Adicionar ao carrinho","quantity":1,"href":"http://teste/index.html#5"},"_options":[],"_discount":50,"_amount":99,"_total":49,"_eventCache":{"change":[[null,null]]}},{"_data":{"cmd":"_cart","add":"1","item_name":"FILA SCM00514","item_image":"images/scm00514-1.png","amount":99,"discount_amount":"50.00","submit":"Adicionar ao carrinho","quantity":1,"href":"http://teste/index.html#5"},"_options":[],"_discount":50,"_amount":99,"_total":49,"_eventCache":{"change":[[null,null]]}}]
```

What I'm looking for is to save each field into separate variables, for example:

```
item = 1 item_name = FILA 1010302, item_image = images/1010302-1.png quantity = 2
```

```
item = 2 item_name = FILA 1010575, item_image = images/1010575-1.png quantity = 1
```

I'm trying several ways using json_decode and  html_entity_decode but I just can't reach the desired output.

Can someone help me on this, I'm assuming this is a fairly easy task, but I'm new to PHP, please try to understand.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are many `item_name`, `item_image` etc. in there.

Comment: I'm sorry the question was not clear enough, I have edited it. The goal is to get some information according to the position of the array. @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an online JSON parser, http://json.parser.online.fr/ , I can see that $_POST['cart'] is an array of 5 objects. Within each object there are 6 more objects (_data, _options, _discount, etc.). Then within the _data object there are nine items. In order to get to the values you would need to look at where they are in that nest of JSON objects.

```
$item_name = json_decode($_POST['cart'], true)[0]["_data"]["item_name"];

$array_of_items_in_cart = json_decode($_POST['cart'], true);
$first_item_in_cart = array_of_items_in_cart[0];
$name_of_first_item_in_cart = first_item_in_cart["_data"]["item_name"];
$first_item_discount = first_item_in_cart["_discount"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Raymond Mutyaba, but isn't this javascript code? What I'm looking for is too decode this on php side. This code on PHP won't give an error?

Comment: As pointed out in the answer "json_decode" is the php command to take JSON and convert it to an array or object

Comment: Sorry about that. I have been writing in javascript lately. I have edited the code to use PHP. Using true inside json_decode turns $_POST['cart'] into an array, and without true it becomes an object.